# Two versions of bash installed, conflicting information from terminal as to which version I am using

Tags: bash, macos

I have Bash v3.x installed natively on Mac running Big Sur. I installed the updated v5.x via homebrew. I had to modify $PATH to add the new bash install location (and to get homebrew working), because homebrew places new installs in '/opt/homebrew/bin'. I did this by adding

> export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH

to my .profile file.

Then, in terminal,

> echo $PATH

displays:

> /opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

My chosen default login shell shown in the OS X settings GUI is

> /opt/homebrew/bin/bash

When I open a terminal window, I can see in the active menu bar that it is running bash as default, but oddly enough, upon opening, terminal shows:

> The default interactive shell is now zsh.
> To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
> For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

That seems weird, but maybe that information is referring to how zsh is "default" in OS X in general-- but I could swear that previously, it would show that bash is in fact my default shell.

I tried this:

> chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash [user]

And I get:

> Changing shell for [user]

> chsh: no changes made

And, entering:

> bash --version

displays:

> GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release, etc.

Yet, typing:

> echo $BASH_VERSION

displays:

> 3.2.57(1)-release

If I enter the command

> bash

terminal brings up

> bash-5.1$

behind my cursor prompt.

Then,

> echo $BASH_VERSION

gives

> 5.1.8(1)-release

Shouldn't the v.5.x.x launch right off the bat? Why do I get conflicting information on what version I am on using the "echo $BASH_VERSION" before I invoke bash specifically?

Comment: Looks to me like you have a couple more steps to go, e.g. update /etc/shells & /private/etc/shells and update your user’s shell with `chpass`. There are guides available on how/what needs to be changed, e.g. https://www.shell-tips.com/mac/upgrade-bash/